# How to automatically add the permission "edit" on a node to a user who is not the author?

Tags: 6, users

I'm in D6

I have a node type "Person" and a node type "Company"

Each node "Person" has :

- an unique field-node-reference to a node "Company"
- an unique field-user-reference (to a user)

So, several persons can belong to the same company

Use case :

- The person P1.1 (belongs to company C1) creates a node (article)

How to automaticly grant edit permission on this article to an other person (P1.2) who belongs to the same company (C1) ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Install [Content Access](http://drupal.org/project/content_access) and [ACL](http://drupal.org/project/acl), and then use [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) to add Person 1.2 as a person able to edit that content.

---

You may find this question helpful: [Node access by role or user, what module(s) should I use?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/13679/node-access-by-role-or-user-what-modules-should-i-use)

> The Content Access module gives you role permissions at the content type and (optionally) node level. By default, node level permissions are disabled but you can enable it on a type-by-type basis.
>
> If you install ACL module, Content Access can give you per user permissions at the content type and node level.